# mysql server crashes, and reported problems with a table

Tags: mysql, crash, debian, myisam, repair

I have a large phpBB forum running on a Debian server.  For the last couple of months, I get a periodic mySQL crash (approx every 10-14 days).  This manifests itself by showing a "too many connection 1040" error.  If I restart the service, I then get an error that one of the phpbb tables "is marked crashed and the last (automatic?) repair failed [144]".

If I manually log into mysql and run a REPAIR on the table, this fixes things - the repair takes a long time - the table in question has 1.5m+ records.  After this, things run fine until the whole thing repeats 10 days ish later.

If I run a `systemctl status mysqld` I'm seeing a few lines saying:

```
Jun 05 05:20:01 servername mysqld[1105]: 2020-06-05  5:20:01 140590520212224 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './phpbb_posts' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
Jun 05 05:20:01 servername mysqld[1105]: 2020-06-05  5:20:01 140590520212224 [ERROR] mysqld: Table 'phpbb_posts' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
```

but as said, things are running OK.

Doing a bit of Googling, it seems shutting the mysql service down and running:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/$DATABASE_NAME
myisamchk -r $TABLE_NAME
myisamchk -r -v -f $TABLE_NAME
```

could well fix things. I'm happy to try that - presumably I just back up the relevant DATABASE_NAME file beforehand in case anything goes wrong?  In which case I cna just drop it back in place?  Presumably the command will take a long time to run given the size of the table?

Before I try this, I'd quite like to understand what's happened and what this fix will do.  If anyone can explain I'd be very grateful :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how much did you set max_connections ?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";`

Comment: Set to 200 - is that good or bad?!

Comment: depends on how much RAM you have it can be a lot. set it to 100 and test it if it is more stable.

Answer (score 0):

You have found one important reason to switch from `ENGINE=MyISAM` to `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb